# DLNA server app for streaming videos locally

Tags: android, streaming, dlna, web-browser

I have jellybean device with broken Display, I decided put a sim in it and turn it into internet hotspot , later i inserted a SD card and installed an app called wifi file transfer pro, to use my phone as Local storage Device.This software also has folder view feature and web interface is really good.

The problem with [wifi file transfer pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransferpro&hl=en) is that you cannot stream video through web browser or vlc, we have to download the complete video to watch it,i even tried turning off ssl encryption, but it didn't help.

To stream video i installed an app called [dlna server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.al.dlnaserver&hl=en_IN), although video streaming worked flawlessly, the problem with this app was that , when we define root directory it lists all files in all folders in a single list, so bascically not user friendly web interface.

So im looking for an apps whose web interface supports folder viewing and at the same can support streaming video

PS. prior to this i have tried

1. Bubble uPNp- problem- it streams directly to device like smart tv which are connect to same wifi. this is not usefull, i need to stream in other mobile devices
2. Pixel media-even this doesnt provide a link that i can open in a browser
3. my dlna server-same as above
4. Servers ultimate pro-same as above, it doesnt give an ip address to which i can connect on other devices.
5. Server cast -same as above
6. Plex- jelly bean not supported
7. Ftp file server- very laggy and slow transfer speed.
8. [WiFi File server Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mins.wfm.activity&hl=en), it requires me to connect to a hotspot, but my phone it self is supposed to be a hotspot

PPS,why all of these on android Phone, because it consumes 0.5 -1 watt but functions as reliable Router , wireless file storage device and lots of usefull apps are there on android platform.

## Requirement

1. it should support jellybean sd
2. it should give out an ip address to which i can connect to with web browser in my iPad or windows
3. The web interface should be user friendly unlike [dlna server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.al.dlnaserver&hl=en_IN)
4. It should support video streaming like [dlna server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.al.dlnaserver&hl=en_IN)

### Update

1. Servers ultimate pro -when I opens VLC on my other device and headed to connection section, it automatically showed the server which i had created.but the problem , im not able to stream Videos,when i click on the video it keeps loading.
2. Servers ultimate pro- as a workaround i created Native DLNA server, the streaming is lag free.it works on both windows and iOS VLC app
3. It turns out the Servers ultimate pro app shows ip address only when my broken screen device is connected to a wifi.
4. i think i found a solution , the native dlna is working flawlessly,both on windows and iPad VLC, but ,i cant play it in Cnx player etc. specific client software with supports DLNA like VLC is a necessity for this method to work. so i feel web interface is a hard requirement

Comment: Just making sure you've seen/checked through: https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia which have lists of various DLNA or streaming apps. But you should make your question clearer as to the scenario/configurations your are trying to achieve - Android to TV, Android to Android, etc. as I think VLC should be able to do it, but failing on some requirement I don't understand.

Comment: vlc on android is unable to act as a host, it can connect to a host and stream. moreover unable to connect dlna server in windows VLC. ip adress with web interface is a better solution

Comment: i hope my question is clear now

Comment: You should state if using a web browser as client on iPad/Windows is a hard requirement or you can use a client app which does X.

Comment: i think i found a solution , the native dlna is working flawlessly.both on windows and iPad VLC, but ,i cant play in Cnx player etc. specific client software like VLC is a necessitty for this method to work. so i feel web interface is a hard requirememt